# Wrong method call generated by compiler

Tags: c++

Windows 7
cygwin 1.7.20
gcc 4.5.3

I have a method in one of my classes, enqueue(const PTR X, const void* operation), when an attempt is made to call it, another method is actually called, enqueue(bool X)' When the original method is changed to, enqueue(const PTR X) it is called correctly. I can't figure out what I might have done to provoke this behavior. The code is compilable.

```
/****** SlipDef.h ******/

#ifndef SLIPDEF_H
#define SLIPDEF_H
# include <string>
# include "SlipPointer.h"
using namespace std;
namespace slip {
    typedef unsigned char   UCHAR;
    typedef signed   char   CHAR;
    typedef unsigned short  USHORT;
    typedef signed   short  SHORT;
    typedef unsigned int    UINT;
    typedef signed   int    INT;
    typedef unsigned long   ULONG;
    typedef signed   long   LONG;
    typedef float           FLOAT;
    typedef double          DOUBLE;
    typedef SlipPointer *   PTR;
    typedef SlipPointer *   STRING;
} // namespace slip
#endif  /* SLIPDEF_H */
/****** SlipHeader.h ******/

#ifndef _SLIPHEADER_H
#define _SLIPHEADER_H
# include <string>
# include "SlipDef.h"
namespace slip {

   class SlipHeader {
   public:
      SlipHeader&       enqueue(SlipHeader& X);
      SlipHeader&       enqueue(bool X);
      SlipHeader&       enqueue(UCHAR X);
      SlipHeader&       enqueue(CHAR X);
      SlipHeader&       enqueue(ULONG X);
      SlipHeader&       enqueue(LONG X);
      SlipHeader&       enqueue(DOUBLE X);
      SlipHeader&       enqueue(const PTR X, const void* operation);
      SlipHeader&       enqueue(const string& X, bool constFlag = false);
      SlipHeader&       enqueue(const string* X, bool constFlag = false);
    };
};
#endif  /* SLIPHEADER_H */

/****** SlipPointer.h ******/

#ifndef SLIPPOINTER_H
#define SLIPPOINTER_H
using namespace std;
namespace slip {

   class SlipPointer { 
   public:
   };
} // namespace slip
#endif  /* SLIPPOINTER_H */

/****** TheOtherHeader.h ******/

#ifndef _THEOTHERHEADER_H
#define _THEOTHERHEADER_H
# include <string>
# include "SlipDef.h"
namespace slip {

   class TheOtherHeader {
   public:
      TheOtherHeader&   enqueue(TheOtherHeader& X);
      TheOtherHeader&   enqueue(bool X);
      TheOtherHeader&   enqueue(UCHAR X);
      TheOtherHeader&   enqueue(CHAR X);
      TheOtherHeader&   enqueue(ULONG X);
      TheOtherHeader&   enqueue(LONG X);
      TheOtherHeader&   enqueue(DOUBLE X);
      TheOtherHeader&   enqueue(const PTR X);
      TheOtherHeader&   enqueue(const string& X, bool constFlag = false);
      TheOtherHeader&   enqueue(const string* X, bool constFlag = false);
    };
};
#endif  /* _THEOTHERHEADER_H */

/****** main.cpp ******/

# include "SlipHeader.h"
#include "TheOtherHeader.h"
# include <string>
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace slip;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   SlipPointer*    ptr    = new SlipPointer();
   SlipHeader*     header = new SlipHeader();
   TheOtherHeader* theOtherHeader = new TheOtherHeader();
   header->enqueue(ptr);
   theOtherHeader->enqueue(ptr);
return 0;
}

/****** SlipHeader.cpp ******/

# include <string>
# include <iostream>
# include "SlipDef.h"
# include "SlipHeader.h"
namespace slip {
   static void* ptrOP;
   SlipHeader& SlipHeader::enqueue(SlipHeader& X) { cout << "enqueue(SlipHeader& X) wrong answer" << endl; return *new SlipHeader();}
   SlipHeader& SlipHeader::enqueue(bool X)      { cout << "enqueue(bool X) wrong answer" << endl;      return *new SlipHeader();}
   SlipHeader& SlipHeader::enqueue(UCHAR X)     { cout << "enqueue(UCHAR X) wrong answer" << endl;     return *new SlipHeader();}
   SlipHeader& SlipHeader::enqueue(CHAR X)      { cout << "enqueue(CHAR X) wrong answer" << endl;      return *new SlipHeader();}
   SlipHeader& SlipHeader::enqueue(ULONG X)     { cout << "enqueue(ULONG X) wrong answer" << endl;     return *new SlipHeader();}
   SlipHeader& SlipHeader::enqueue(LONG X)      { cout << "enqueue(LONG X) wrong answer" << endl;      return *new SlipHeader();}
   SlipHeader& SlipHeader::enqueue(DOUBLE X)    { cout << "enqueue(DOUBLE X) wrong answer" << endl;    return *new SlipHeader();}
   SlipHeader& SlipHeader::enqueue(const PTR X, const void* operation = ptrOP) {
      cout << "enqueue(PTR X) right answer" << endl; return *new SlipHeader();
   };
   SlipHeader& SlipHeader::enqueue(const string& X, bool constFlag) { cout << "enqueue(string& X) wrong answer" << endl; return *new SlipHeader();}
   SlipHeader& SlipHeader::enqueue(const string* X, bool constFlag) { cout << "enqueue(string* X) wrong answer" << endl; return *new SlipHeader();}
};
/****** TheOtherHeader.cpp ******/

# include <string>
# include <iostream>
# include "SlipDef.h"
# include "TheOtherHeader.h"
namespace slip {
   static void* ptrOP;
   TheOtherHeader& TheOtherHeader::enqueue(TheOtherHeader& X) { cout << "enqueue(TheOtherHeader& X) wrong answer" << endl; return *new TheOtherHeader();}
   TheOtherHeader& TheOtherHeader::enqueue(bool X)      { cout << "enqueue(bool X) wrong answer" << endl;      return *new TheOtherHeader();}
   TheOtherHeader& TheOtherHeader::enqueue(UCHAR X)     { cout << "enqueue(UCHAR X) wrong answer" << endl;     return *new TheOtherHeader();}
   TheOtherHeader& TheOtherHeader::enqueue(CHAR X)      { cout << "enqueue(CHAR X) wrong answer" << endl;      return *new TheOtherHeader();}
   TheOtherHeader& TheOtherHeader::enqueue(ULONG X)     { cout << "enqueue(ULONG X) wrong answer" << endl;     return *new TheOtherHeader();}
   TheOtherHeader& TheOtherHeader::enqueue(LONG X)      { cout << "enqueue(LONG X) wrong answer" << endl;      return *new TheOtherHeader();}
   TheOtherHeader& TheOtherHeader::enqueue(DOUBLE X)    { cout << "enqueue(DOUBLE X) wrong answer" << endl;    return *new TheOtherHeader();}
   TheOtherHeader& TheOtherHeader::enqueue(const PTR X) {
      cout << "enqueue(PTR X) right answer" << endl; return *new TheOtherHeader();
   };
   TheOtherHeader& TheOtherHeader::enqueue(const string& X, bool constFlag) { cout << "enqueue(string& X) wrong answer" << endl; return *new TheOtherHeader();}
   TheOtherHeader& TheOtherHeader::enqueue(const string* X, bool constFlag) { cout << "enqueue(string* X) wrong answer" << endl; return *new TheOtherHeader();}
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your header file defines this:

```
SlipHeader&       enqueue(const PTR X, const void* operation);
```

And you call it like this:

```
header->enqueue(ptr);
```

The compiler does not consider the declaration as a valid match for the function call (you only pass one argument, and do not declare a default argument for the second), and picks one of the ones that can be called with a single argument instead. <strike>Why it picks the `bool` one would take a little more digging through the standard.</strike>

The fact that you supply a default argument for the second argument in the actual definition of the function is invisible to the compiler when it compiles your `main()`, and so is not considered. You should move the default argument into the header (and in fact, if you have warnings on, you should probably get a warning based on the way you have it arranged right now).

Edit: As aschepler points out below, the reason the `bool` version gets called is it's the only allowed automatic conversion for a `[const] void *`.

Comment: Because `void *` converts to `bool`?

Comment: @BenJackson That was my thought, but converting `void *` to one of the wider integral types would "lose less information", so I wasn't entirely sure if the standard allows only that conversion, or if it might allow automatic conversion to, e.g. a `long`, and I don't have my copy handy to look it up... It also might be dependent on the specific version of the standard that's being compiled to...

Comment: There is a standard conversion from any pointer type to `bool` [4.12].  There is no standard conversion from pointer type to any other integral type.  Checking whether or not a pointer is nulled is safe and portable.  You can `reinterpret_cast` a pointer to "an integral type large enough to hold it", but that's entirely implementation-defined and so not allowed implicitly.

Comment: @aschepler And that's the part I couldn't quite recall... Thanks for the pointer... ;P

Comment: To you all (ya'll) thanks. Thanks for taking the time. As pointed out above, I thought that the default value was allowed in either source or header. No error message was given, which caused family and friends to avoid me. The lack of any diagnostic message is a real disappointment (I'm using gcc 4.5.3, and oldie). To rage for a second, the only complaint with gcc is the gratuitous lack of diagnostic messages (sometimes) and the difficulty in interpreting (some) message that I get. Hopefully the lack of diagnostics has been corrected. gcc solicits help in identifying ambiguous messages.

Comment: @ArthurSchwarez It is allowed in either source or header, but it must be visible anywhere its behavior is dependent on it, which is why it will most often be seen in the declaration in a header. But you'll find them in source files as well, but more likely on static functions that aren't visible outside that translation unit.

Answer (score 1):

You have default arguments to `const void* operation`. However, you set these default arguments in the implementation rather than the header - it should be the other way around:

```
// header
void f(int x=5);

// implementation
void f(int x) { }
```

The reason for this is simple, if you call `header->enqueue(ptr)` in the main code the compiler only knows the information given by the header. If the header does not contain the default argument the compiler does not know of the existence of a default argument at that point.

Comment: Can't do this in the real code. It leads to a cycle in the headers. Is there an alternative or do I have the restructure?

Comment: @ArthurSchwarez perhaps you can use forward declarations?

Comment: Nope. However I have done the restructuring. Tedious. Unappealing. But showing that through diligence, perseverance, and total lack of understanding I can (really) accomplish something. Anything. Many thanks. I thought that the positioning of the argument default values (header/source) by a user was optional, either place being OK but not in both places. I was wrong. Sigh.